# What is a good approach for dealing with the uploading of image sequences

Tags: image, upload, sequence

I am implementing the back end for an online store.  The store receives new products periodically.  Each product comes with a sequence of images for a 3D rotation effect on the website.  What is a good approach for uploading these images onto the web store?  I'm currently using a web form but uploading each image using a separate upload form element feels like a waste of time.  These sequences can have anywhere from 12-50 frames.  Any suggestions for a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a minimum amount of change from your current solution you can add the `multiple` attribute to your file input box, and update your back-end to support it.

You can then select multiple files at once with a modern browser, for instance [Firefox 3.6](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/12/multiple-file-input-in-firefox-3-6/). Try:

```
<input type="file" multiple=""/>
```